# How can i convert a string into a ZZ number?

Tags: c++, ntl, elgamal

I'm using the [NTL library](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/) to implement ElGamal encryption/decryption algorithm.
I've got it to the point that it's working but the algorithm wants the message to be converted to integers so it can be encrypted.
So if i input a number like 1234 everything works ok but how would i go to be able to convert a C++ string (std::string) to a ZZ number and then back from that ZZ number to a string?

**LE**:

ZZ it's a class that represent a large number.
Ex: 18287348238476283658234881728316274273671623781254124517353

So basically i'm looking to take "Hello World" for example and run it char by char and get the ascii code of the chars so i'll get a number: "72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100"
And then i need to convert this number back to string "Hello World"

Or maybe there's a better way.

Comment: What is ZZ number ? Frankly, I tried Google couldn't find it

Comment: `ZZ` is NTL's infinite-precision integer class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do it:

```
std::string str("1234567890");
NTL::ZZ number(NTL::INIT_VAL, str.c_str());
```

Now notice that:

```
std::cout << str << std::endl; // prints 1234567890
std::cout << number << std::endl; // prints 1234567890
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer from the NTL author's website:

> In addition to the conversions listed, there is a generic conversion
>   from a **C-strings** (i.e., const char *) to any type T, which is
>   implemented using templates using the input operator >> for type T.
>   So, for example, you can write

```
    ZZ x = conv<ZZ>("99999999999999999999999");
```

Source: http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/conversions.txt

I tried it, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest solution is to realize that you can convert `char`s to `unsigned int`s, and `unsigned int`s to `ZZ` numbers. Then treat the string as a base-256 number. For instance, "abc" would be 256*"ab" + "c", or 65536 * "a" + 256 * "b" + "c", or `((ZZ(unsigned('a')*256) + ZZ(unsigned('b'))*256) + ZZ(unsigned('c'))`,

Comment: and on the other end, when i have the number how to convert it back to string?

Comment: iterate `nextchar=val % 256;val = val / 256;` until val is 0. This, admittedly, builds the string backwards, but it's just a case of reversing the string.

Comment: True - you get to pick once whether you want little-endian or big-endian, the other conversion will just have to match that. Both endiannnesses are equally valid, and it makes sense to match your platform convention.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Works like a charm. Thank you both MSalters and vatine